# Construct a function which satisfies the following conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

I am struggling with the following routine problem :
Construct a holomorphic function f(z) with pole of order 2 at 0, an essential singularity at 1 and with residues 1 and 0 respectively.

In general what is an efficient way to tackle these kind of problems?

Answer (score 0):

> A function with a pole of order $n$ at $z=c$ with residue $a_{-1}$ looks like

$$\sum_{m=-n}^{\infty}a_{m}(z-c)^{m},\quad a_{-n}\neq0$$

> A function with an essential singularity at $z=c$ with residue $a_{-1}$ looks like

$$
\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}a_m(z-c)^m,\quad\nexists m\in\mathbb N: a_{-k}=0\;\forall \;k>m
$$
So we make the following ansatz
$$
f(z)=\sum_{m=-2}^{\infty}a_mz^{m}+\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}b_m(z-1)^m
$$
where $$\begin{align}
&a_{-2}\neq0\\
&a_{-1}=1\\
&b_{-1}=0\\
&\nexists m\in\mathbb N: b_{-k}=0\;\forall \;k>m
\end{align}$$
To enforce the requirements and make our lives easier by turning our ansatz into known functions we choose
$$
\begin{align}
&a_{-2}=1\\
&b_{-m}={1\over(m-2)!}\;\forall\; m\ge2\\
&a_m=b_m=0\;\forall\;m>-1\\
\end{align}
$$
So our function becomes
$$
f(z)={1\over z^2}+{1\over z}+\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}{(z-1)^{-m}\over(m-2)!}=\color{blue}{\underbrace{{1\over z^2}+{1\over z}}_{g(z)}+\underbrace{{e^{1\over z-1}\over(z-1)^2}}_{h(z)}}
$$
Letting $z-1=p$ we see 
$$
g(z)={1\over1+p^2+2p}+{1\over 1+p}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(p^2+2p)^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^np^{n}\\
\implies\text{Rez}_{z=1}(g)=\text{Rez}_{p=0}(g)=0\\
\implies\text{Rez}_{z=1}(f)=\text{Rez}_{z=1}(g+h)=\text{Rez}_{z=1}(g)+\text{Rez}_{z=1}(h)=\text{Rez}_{z=1}(h)=0
$$
Again
$$
h(z)=e^{-\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)z^k=\sum_{m=0}^\infty{1\over m!}\left(-\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\right)^m\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)z^k\\
\implies \text{Rez}_{z=0}(h)=0
$$
Using linearity of $\text{Rez}_{z=0}$ we see $\text{Rez}_{z=0}(f)=\text{Rez}_{z=0}(g)=1$.

As $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C\setminus\{0,1\}$  we have found a function that meets all the requirements.